# Nest can't resolve dependencies of the ICommandBusAdapter

Tags: nestjs

Trying to use my ICommandBusAdapter.ts in my CreateUserAction.ts, but I get the following error:
`[ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the ICommandBusAdapter (?). Please make sure that the argument at index [0] is available in the AdapterModule context`

I have created a `AdapterModule` that will share all providers to others modules, but it doesn't seems work.

Any idea ?

AppModule.ts

```js
import { UserModule } from './User/UserModule';
import { AdapterModule } from './Common/AdapterModule';

@Module({
  imports: [AdapterModule, UserModule, // ...],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

AdapterModule.ts

```js
import { CommandBusAdapter } from 'src/Infrastructure/Adapter/Bus/CommandBusAdapter';

const providers = [
  { provide: 'ICommandBusAdapter', useClass: CommandBusAdapter },
  // ...
];

@Module({
  providers: [...providers],
  exports: [...providers],
})
export class AdapterModule {}
```

UserModule.ts

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CreateUserAction } from 'src/Infrastructure/Action/User/CreateUserAction';
@Module({
  controllers: [CreateUserAction],
})
export class UserModule {}
```

CommandBusAdapter.ts

```js
import { CommandBus, ICommand } from '@nestjs/cqrs';
import { ICommandBusAdapter } from 'src/Application/Adapter/Bus/ICommandBusAdapter';

@Injectable()
export class CommandBusAdapter implements ICommandBusAdapter {
  constructor(private readonly commandBus: CommandBus) {}

  execute = (command: ICommand) => {
    return this.commandBus.execute(command);
  };
}
```

CreateUserAction.ts

```js
import { ICommandBusAdapter } from 'src/Application/Adapter/Bus/ICommandBusAdapter';

export class CreateUserAction {
  constructor(
    @Inject('ICommandBusAdapter')
    private readonly commandBus: ICommandBusAdapter,
  ) {}
// ...
```

Comment: Where is `CommandBus` provided?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you remember to add the `CqrsModule` to your application?

```
import { CqrsModule } from '@nestjs/cqrs';

@Module({
  imports: [CqrsModule]
  ....
```

Without it there won't anything providing the CommandBus which you're trying to inject.

You can see an example here:
https://github.com/kamilmysliwiec/nest-cqrs-example/blob/master/src/heroes/heroes.module.ts

Comment: Feel free to upvote or mark this as the answer if it worked for you